# O domínio do site será br.stackoverflow.com mesmo?

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Porque foi escolhido o **br** para colocar como subdomínio?

Não seria melhor ter usado pt.stackoverflow.com?

Já havia me "irritado" um pouco no e-mail enviado notificando que o site iria entrar em funcionamento as referências ao Brasil, quando esse site nunca foi proposto para ser brasileiro e sim para falantes do português. Sou brasileiro.

Porque o **pt**? **pt** já é usado em outros sites para indicar a língua.

Se não for possível a troca, pelo menos que se crie o **pt** em adição ao **br** e preferencialmente que o **pt** seja adotado oficialmente deixando o **br** como legado.

Comment: Eu diria que escolheram **br** para agradar os brasileiros. Quem sabe foi para agradar a pessoa que deu a idéia de criar o site. Só o @gabe sabe responder essa.

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski Se for isso, posso afirmar que desagradou essa pessoa :)

Comment: Acho que a pergunta deveria ser tagueada como [meta-tag:debate], e não bug. Foi uma decisão da equipe da SE, que você está contestando (com toda razão). E, num debate, a resposta do Marco Aurélio funcionaria como resposta mesmo. :-)

Comment: Eu fiquei entre o debate, bug e novo-recurso. Coloquei bug porque não é exatamente um recurso que estou pedindo, acho que foi feito errado, estou contestando e não foi minha intenção de debater isso, apesar do texto deixar essa margem. Vou ver se quebro o galho do Marco Aurélio :)

Comment: Eu, como brasileiro, acho que o mais natural seria usar "pt", também. Não creio que a maioria das pessoas dos outros países iria achar ruim, mas soa estranho e dá uma impressão errada, mesmo porque a pessoa não precisa sequer ser de um país lusófono para participar. Aposto que, se o SO original fosse ter um prefixo, seria "en" e não "us". Enfim, é um detalhe, mas me parece relevante.

Comment: Este assunto foi levantado no metão: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214167/is-stackoverflow-em-portugues-for-brazilians-only

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Atualização (por David Fullerton)

Discutimos o assunto e decidimos mudar para pt.stackoverflow.com, que é consistente com o nome do site.

Temos de aguardar até o final do beta privado para aplicar a mudança, pois ela vai causar o logout de todos os usuários, e no beta privado seria necessário ter uma URL especial para fazer o login novamente.

> <sup>**Update (please translate)**</sup>
>   <sup>We discussed this and we're going to change it to pt.stackoverflow.com to be consistent with the name.</sup>
>   <sup>We can't do that until the end of private beta because it will log everyone out and in private beta you need a special URL to get back in.</sup>

---

#### Resposta original do Gabe:

Por partes:

- Talvez a gente consiga stackoverflow.com.br, mas no final das contas ele funcionaria mais como redirecionamento pra cá (por uma série de motivos, tipo compartilhamento de login com outros sites da rede...)
- A escolha de onde/quando usar *BR* ou *PT* foi tema de mais conversas do que eu gostaria durante o projeto. Nós tivemos que pesar muitas coisas a respeito de quem é nosso público alvo, quais são os planos para outras línguas, como todas as comunidades vão se comparar, e outras coisas... Basicamente, não foi no dado.

  - O Brasil tem em torno de 80% da população que fala português. Se considerarmos a população de **programadores** é provável que essa proporção aumente. Então é natural que o site tenda a ter uma familiaridade maior para quem é o Brasil (eu sou brasileiro, a localização foi claramente feita para PT_BR, essas coisas).
  - O número de programadores no Brasil que não tem conhecimento de inglês, e que não vão/querem/podem aprender a língua é maior, em termos absolutos e relativos, do que em Portugal. O SOPT é, obviamente de todo falante de português que quiser usá-lo, mas se todo programador no Brasil e Portugal falasse inglês, ele não existiria... Então não é segredo nenhum que o Brasil é o nosso maior motivador para o projeto
  - A idéia é que esse seja o primeiro de outros sites em "língua estrangeira", então coisas como padronização são importantes, desde que não interfiram com os ponto de cima.

## Stack Overflow Brasil?

O Brasil é o maior alvo do site, certamente. E por causa disso qualquer decisão que afetasse a entrada de mais brasileiros é evitada. Nós precisamos fazer com que o site fosse receptivo à todos de língua portuguesa, mas deixar bem claro para os brasileiros que nunca ouviram falar do SO que eles são o principal motivador da idéia. Não queremos fazer o site todo em verde e amarelo (primeiro porque é brega....), nem chamá-lo de Stack Overflow Brasil porque são coisas excludentes **demais**, mas este foi um site pensado para o público brasileiro.

A decisão de um site que tende ao Brasil foi tomada quando começou o processo de localização. Todos os textos no site estão em PT_BR, algumas outras *coisinhas* foram pensadas para a cultura brasileira. Fazer tudo isso e afirmar que "esse é um site igualitário para todos os lusófonos" faz ainda menos sentido que ter `br` na URL.

Comment: Concordo com todos os pontos, só acho que de alguma forma está excluindo um pouco os que não são brasileiros e isso não é bom. O site não foi definido assim mas a palavra final é da equipe. Pode até dizer que é uma atitude imatura das pessoas não brasileiras que não vão usar o site porque ele está sendo direcionado para o brasileiro. Parece que a decisão já foi tomada e que a equipe está ciente dos problemas que isso pode acarretar.

Comment: Minha opinião é que é um problema sem uma solução correta. A gente não pode ferir o público alvo maior em nome da padronização... E não pode esquecer da padronização, para não acabar alienando o resto do mundo. Qualquer caminho ia trazer problemas

Comment: Seja lá qual for a decisão, é preciso sincronizar o "sobrenome" do site. Hoje eu estou lendo "stackoverflow em português", e não "stackoverflow Brasil" no logo.

Comment: Concordo que, sendo o Brasil o maior publico alvo, o site site será *um pouquinho* tendencioso, e concordo com isso. Mas do meu ponto de vista (sou brasileiro e português, a programar em Portugal) usar *pt* no domínio não iria, de maneira nenhuma, afastar nenhum programador brasileiro e irá, com certeza, afastar programadores portugueses.

Answer (score 14):

Também achei esquisito o `br.stackoverflow.com`. A Wikipedia utiliza o subdomínio `pt`. Se você pensar bem `br` nem é um código ISO para idioma (`pt_BR` é) então faria mais sentido usar o `pt`.

Quando for o caso de liberar "stack overflows" em idiomas que são mais distribuídos geograficamente que o português (como por exemplo o Espanhol) o uso de códigos de país seria ainda mais sem sentido.

Comment: Normalmente esse tipo de postagem cabe mais como comentário na questão já que ela não responde a questão. Normalmente esse tipo de questão só o pessoal da equipe (aqui basicamente é o Gabe) consegue dar uma resposta. Continue contribuindo, você pega o jeito logo, eu fiz bobagens enormes quando comecei.

Comment: Desculpa denovo, estou tentando. Hahahaha. Noob infinito aqui ;D Acha que crio um comentário e apago a resposta?

Comment: Marco, eu discordo do bigown quanto a isto. Em perguntas do tipo "discussão" ou "debate" no meta, as "respostas" podem ser simplesmente sua opinião sobre o assunto. E acho que isto é mais um debate que um bug.

Comment: Não precisa se desculpar não, você não cometeu erro grave ou ofendeu alguém. De qualquer forma mudei para debate e quebrei seu galho. Agora a resposta é pertinente :)