# Descrição do link 'feedback' fora do padrão

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Lá no rodapé do SOpt ao passar o mouse no link feedback é exibido o endereço: 
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ após clicar nele o redirecionamento para o meta é feito sem problemas. Acredito que correto seria: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se não me engano as urls tinham **br** no beta privado e depois foi decidido que mudaria para **pt**.

Perguntas relacionadas:

[O domínio do site será br.stackoverflow.com mesmo?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/50/91)

[Metão - Is “stackoverflow em Português” for Brazilians only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214167/238766)